# GridView Lostfocus in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Can anybody let me know how to display a Pop up to  confirm if he wants to save the changes ,when a record is in Edit mode in Gridview 
and user Clicks or tabs away from the row.

Thanks in advance
Divya.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, from your description I understood that you have automatic saving of changes on grid lostfocus client event? because if this is not true, then you don't need dialog to prevent saving, because gridview stays in edit mode until user clicks save or cancel(postback the page), right?

So, why then you want that confirmation dialog/popup functionality?

cheers
Marko